# Requesting and forwarding between servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
    request.setAttribute("lstCart", cart.Items);
    request.setAttribute("subTotal", total);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/ViewCart.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This is my Code. Where I have put cart.Items in a session.

I would like to know instead of forwarding it to a jsp page, how can i forward it to a servlet that gets the values of the session variables, and then forwards it to ViewCart.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `response.sendRedirect("servletUrl");`.

Then get the session value the same way you do in your servlet.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession("sessionName")
```

Then forward it to ViewCart.jsp the same thing you did in your code. I'm not on my work station and I little forgot it, so I cannot validate it. But I know this is the way I did this.

And why do you need another Servlets? you can already get the session in your current Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward to another servlet like this (based on your url-patterns in web.xml):

```
ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet");
rd.forward(request,response);
```